# Is there any way to find out if SQL Server is using all of CPU cores?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server Web Edition.

I have SQL Server licensed to 16 cores only. I have 48 cores of CPU. Is there any way to know that SQL is reaching or utilizing its peak 16 cores limit all time?

I am having performance issues and not able to find out that if its only SQL Server reaching its all cores limit after which it goes into timeouts and wait state for running queries? When I tested from new relic, and zabbix, it shows SQL transactions are being blocked, and lot of time is being spent.

Is there any way to know SQL is 100% using only 16 cores?...or any way to find out which core SQL Server runs on always?...and on other cores it never runs (due to  license limit)?

My hosting company says SQL Server web edition has 16 cores limit, but at same time they provide license of 24x2 for SQL Server web edition, which we are not sure if its utilizing all CPU cores or not. Please find attached screenshot for reference if the license is using all 48 cores or not.

[image: Server Properties]

Comment: Could you give some more details about that environment? You say you have a CPU with 48 cores but a SQL Server with 16 cores. Is that a virtual machine with 16 vCPUs or a Windows Server on a 48 cores box and SQL Server installed? Do you have anything else installed on the server besides SQL Server? Have you checked [Perfmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-r2-and-2008/cc749154(v%3dws.11))?

Comment: For using all cores you have to use Core-Based Licensing instance and for find out the number of cores , I think after execution of the query you can see with :

SELECT cpu_count
FROM [sys].[dm_os_sys_info]

Comment: How many sockets are provisioned for your 16 cores of CPU? What does [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com/) show when you run it while your queries are being blocked / slow?

Comment: @Ronaldo its dedicated server. i have IIS instlled beside SQL server. did not checked using perform, what metric will help me get those details of sql spu usage?

Answer (score 1):

Paul Randal's article [SQL Server Wait Statistics (or please tell me where it hurts…)](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/) has a query that will help you identify if the low performance you've been experiencing is due to processor utilization.

Regarding the limitation of 16 core for SQL Server Web Edition, you can confirm that info on the [Scale limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver16#Cross-BoxScaleLimits) section of the **Editions and supported features of SQL Server** doc (licencing is a topic not allowed for discussion, I'm posting just to show where that 16 limit core limitation you mentioned came from):

> **Web**
>  Maximum compute capacity used by a single instance - SQL Server Database Engine
>
> Limited to lesser of 4 sockets or 16 cores

Also, J.D. has given you an excellent (free) tool to help you see what's going on during the low performance moments: [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/).

As for the perfmon I mentioned, you can observe the processor activities using the counters **% Processor Time** for the object **Processor**:

[image: Perfmon]

Perfmon will present you one instance for each core and a total. You won't be able to see exactly if SQL Server is the process using the CPU at the moment, but it should give you an overview of your CPU consumption.