# SQL server web edition licensing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

My hosting company says SQL Server web edition has 16 cores limit, but at same time they provide license of 24x2 for SQL Server web edition, which we are not sure if its utilizing all CPU cores or not. Please find attached screenshot for reference if the license is using all 48 cores or not.

Does the picture show that SQL Server is able to utilize all CPU cores fully? Or there is any limitation?

[image: screenshot of number of cores on server]

Comment: Please don't Post [duplicate questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/320872/is-there-any-way-to-find-out-if-sql-server-is-using-all-of-cpu-cores). Rather, improve your existing question with any further information and answers to questions on that question.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the documentation from Microsoft WEB iedition is limited to lesser of 4 sockets or 16 cores

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver16

What is the status of the CPU's in this dmv?

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_schedulers
```

Choosing a server that has a higher number of cores than your license covers can cause CPU skew and wasted CPU power. This is because of the mapping between logical and actual cores. When you use SQL Server with a Client Access License (CAL), some schedulers will be VISIBLE ONLINE and the rest will be VISIBLE OFFLINE. This can lead to performance issues with non-uniform memory access (NUMA) topologies, because of scheduler nodes not being utilized optimally.

For example, if you run SQL Server and it will detect two sockets with 24 cores, and 48 logical processors per socket, which results in a total of 96 logical processors.

If you have a license for only 48 cores, you would see a message similar to the following in the SQL Server error log:

2020-06-08 12:35:27.37 Server SQL Server detected 2 sockets with 24 cores per socket and 48 logical processors per socket, 96 total logical processors; using 48 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.

If you see a difference between the total cores and the number of cores being used by SQL Server, check for CPU usage imbalance or use a server type that has the same number of cores that your license supports.